# Missing method implementations in PHP project

Tags: php, oop, implementation

Recently I got someones PHP site project (and this someone don't wan't to help me), so I have to understand his code. And maybe my answer would be stupid, but...

But there's some methods before class, that are doxumented as in example:

```
namespace Base\Classes;

/**
 * @method int method1()
 * @method $this method2(int $parameter)
 */

class SomeClass extends ParentClass
{
    public $_s_a = false;
    public $_user_roles = [];

    public function SomeClassMethod() {
        somethingDone();
    }
}
```

And as you can see in this example, these documented methods are not implemented in defined class. But what my question is about - this methods are called from another classes and templates. And PHPStorm (my IDE) connects this documentation lines with calls, and `ctrl+B` leads from between references. But I can't find exact implementation of this methods.  They cannot be found in parent classes, they are not in this file. And I thought maybe this is some syntax sugar that I'm not familiar with. Am I right? Or there something I'm missing, and all implementations somewhere in another place? (search by method name in folder gives nothing for me)

Comment: Has parent class the `__call()` method?

Comment: as i can gues this are doc blocks for magic setters and getters methods. so u need to look through the ParentClass and find them out. or, as @Timurib said - find the __call method implementation. the need of the doc blocks is that your ide will not light the call of this methods as an mismatching calls

Comment: Yes, it has. So, as I can understand, there's  some mapping between existed methods and its names, that are passed by calling a method on this class. And I need to dig in this direction. Thanks!

Comment: the methods r not exists - because they r magic. please, check the manual - http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php. the need of the doc blocks is only for ide

Comment: I meant that `__call()` method I saw use some metadata gathered a bit earlier to resolve inaccessible name to something accessible in project. As I said, this code isn't mine, and I have to understand it. And for previous developer (as I can see now) it was an idea. Thanks to all of your, it great help and relief for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP has a few [magic methods](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php), and one of them is [`__call()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call).

When you have an object that implements `__call()` (by itself or by one of the parent classes), you may call an inaccessible method on it, and the `__call()` method will be called instead. This happens, for example, when you call a private method from the outside, or when you call a method that was not defined in code.

When you use such calls to inaccessible methods, IDEs will most likely show a warning that the method does not exist, although the code itself will probably work at runtime. These warnings are quite annoying, so you can add a [`@method`](https://phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/phpdoc/tags/method.html) tag to your class, and the IDE will know that this method exists, and will not show a warning.

So, to support the code that you got from someone, take a look at the `__call()` method implementation. Be aware that this method may be implemented in one of the parent classes, so check them out as well.